# Spark: return null from failed regexp_extract()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose you try to extract a substring from a column of a dataframe. `regexp_extract()` returns a null if the field itself is null, but returns an empty string if field is not null but the expression is not found. How can you return a null value for the latter case?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(None),('foo'),('foo_bar')], StringType())
df.select(regexp_extract('value', r'_(.+)', 1).alias('extracted')).show()

# +---------+
# |extracted|
# +---------+
# |     null|
# |         |
# |      bar|
# +---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(None),('foo'),('foo_bar')], StringType())
df = df.select(regexp_extract('value', r'_(.+)', 1).alias('extracted'))
df.withColumn(
    'extracted',
    when(col('extracted') != '', col('extracted'), lit(None))
).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `regexp_extract()` could ever return `None` for a String type.  One thing you could do is replace empty strings with `None` using a user defined function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame([(None),('foo'),('foo_bar')], StringType())
toNoneUDF = udf(lambda val: None if val == "" else val, StringType())
new_df = df.select(regexp_extract('value', r'_(.+)', 1).alias('extracted'))
new_df.withColumn("extracted", toNoneUDF(new_df.extracted)).show()
```

Comment: I had been using a similar approach based on zero323's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287886/replace-empty-strings-with-none-null-values-in-dataframe). Is it preferable to use a udf as you have done above?

Answer (score 0):

In spark SQL, I've found a solution to **count the number of regex occurrence**, ignoring null values:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN rlike(col, "_(.+)") THEN 1 END)
FROM VALUES (NULL), ("foo"), ("foo_bar"), ("") AS tab(col);
```

Result:

```
1
```

I hope this will help some of you.