# How to convert NONEs to an empty string in a pyspark dataframe when it has nested columns?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with nested columns like below:

```
df_schema = StructType([
    StructField("response", StringType(), True),
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("data", StructType([
      StructField("type", StringType(), True),
      StructField("record", StringType(), True),
      StructField("enteredCycle", StringType(), True),
      StructField("timestamp", StringType(), True),
      StructField("modifiedById", StringType(), True),
      StructField("years", IntegerType(), True),
      StructField("attributes", StructType([
        StructField("mass", ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
        StructField("pace", ArrayType(IntegerType()), True),
        StructField("reflex", ArrayType(StringType()), True)
      ]))
    ]))
])
```

I am getting this dataframe as a resultant of an API call like below.

```
def api_call(parameter: str):
    response = session.get(f"https:url={parameter}", headers=header_data)
    return json.dumps(json.loads(response.text))

udf_call = udf(lambda z:api_call(z),StringType())
```

I am adding this UDF call to one of my dataframe as an extra column like below:

```
df = inputDf.withColumn("api_response", udf_call(col("employee_id")))

# Creating an empty df
# I have multiple api calls. So I am appending all of them into 
# one single dataframe and then writing all of them at once
# rather than write one record at a time (I have 500,00 records)

empty_rdd = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()
empty_df = spark.createDataFrame(empty_rdd, df_schema)
```

Applying schema:

```
json_df = (
    df
    .withColumn("main",from_json(col('api_response'), df_schema)
    .select('response', 'id', 'data.type', 'data.record',....'data.attributes.reflex')
)
empty_df = empty_df.unionAll(json_df)
```

The problem appears when I try to ingest the dataframe as a table:

```
empty_df.write.mode('overwrite').format('parquet').saveAsTable('dbname.tablename')
```

I see this error:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 24 in stage 161.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 24.3 in stage 161.0 (TID 1119) (100.66.2.91 executor 0): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str', from year_loads.py, line 21. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<year_loads.py>", line 21, in <lambda>
  File "<year_loads.py>", line 44, in api_call
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage8.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:757)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextAwareIterator.hasNext(ContextAwareIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1209)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1215)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2241)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:313)
```

My assumption is that there are NONEs in the output that cannot be appended to StringType(). So I implemented a logic to convert all NONEs to an empty string like below. I got this implementation from another stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287886/replace-empty-strings-with-none-null-values-in-dataframe) and changed it according to my requirement.

```
# Get only String Columns
def replace_none_with_empty_str(df: DataFrame):
  string_fields = []
  for i, f in enumerate(df.schema.fields):
      if isinstance(f.dataType, StringType):
          string_fields.append(f.name)
  exprs = [none_as_blank(x).alias(x) if x in string_fields else x for x in df.columns]
  df.select(*exprs)
  return df

# NULL/NONE to blank logic
def none_as_blank(x):
    return when(col(x) != None, col(x)).otherwise('')


non_nulls_df = replace_none_with_empty_str(empty_df)
non_nulls_df.write.mode('overwrite').format('parquet').saveAsTable('dbname.tablename')
```

But I still see the same error even after applying the above `NULL/NONE to blank logic`.
Is my assumption and work around correct? Is my logic being properly applied on all String columns particularly nested stirng columns?  If not, could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I correct it?
Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: You did not accept any answers in the last year. Strange...

Comment: @werner Was about to answer this, but I noticed your comment. I see that OP is a prolific questioner, but [last time he accepted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7119501/metadata?tab=questions&sort=newest) was Apr 22, 2022.

Comment: @werner & kashyap I get back to people in comments after I try their suggestions. Just as you checked my questions, I did that in almost all of my older posts. In the last one year, for most of them I couldn't get an answer to accept, although I upvoted if I at least get hints if not the entire answers. But in the most recent times, I agree about your points. My role changed and most of the time I spend on is on design and less on code and its making me forget to comeback to my questions I asked. I'll change that part from my side and engage more. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your error stack trace, and more specifically the last entries on your stack:

```
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:86)
```

You see that the error seems to happen when executing your UDF, before your post-processing. With the information that we got here, I would guess your `api_call` function is the issue. More specifically, your return value might be `None`. What about trying something like the following:

```py
def api_call(parameter: str):
    response = session.get(f"https:url={parameter}", headers=header_data)
    return json.dumps(json.loads(response.text)) or ""
```

The `or ""` would catch you returning a `NoneType` and just return an empty string. This means you would have a fully empty record, but that would be the case anyway because your value is of NoneType.